# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ convergent or divergent?

I tried ratio test but didn't seem to work, and I also know that the limit goes to zero, but I can't say its convergence because then.

Can someone show me a test to see if its convergent or divergent?

Comment: Hint : $\frac{n-1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @mikevandernaald can you tell me which test you want me to work with?

Comment: It looks an awful lot like harmonic series.  What do you know about that series?

Comment: The "p-test" I suppose.  But have you ever seen the Harmonic Series before, if not you should check this out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Being able to identify this sum when it comes up is a good skill to have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a few people have pointed you in the right direction, but you still need help.

The limit comparison test.  If you have two series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ and you know what whether a_n converges or diverges.

And,
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{a_n} = M$ for some bounded M not equal to $0.$ Then $b_n$ converges when $a_n$ converges and diverges when $a_n$ diverges.

And this one I like but is slightly stupid.

the direct comparison test.... $\frac{n-1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n}$ so you can't run the direct comparison test vs. $\frac{1}{n}$.  However   $\frac{n-1}{n^2} > \frac{1}{2n}$ for all $n>2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use limit comparison test with $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: but $\frac{1}{n}$ is larger than $\frac{n-1}{n^2}$, if I want to show $\frac{n-1}{n^2}$ divergence, shouldn't I find something diverge that is smaller?

Comment: @mamath: You should probably read what the ``limit" comparison test says.

Comment: I just did, and I still don't get what you mean

Comment: @mamath here $a_n = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ and take $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ then $\lim_n \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_n \frac{n^2 - n}{n^2} = 1 $ and so by limit comparison test, since $ \sum_n b_n$ diverges then so does $\sum_n a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy condensation test, its convergence is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \frac{2^n - 1}{2^{2n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}
$$
so...

Comment: I'm sorry but I never learned this test.......can you show another way?

Comment: @mamath Its [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Estimate) is really simple, just try to produce a version for this question only.

Comment: This is my favorite, thanks for mentioning this @Henry W. I had never heard of the "Cauchy condensation test"..

Comment: @mikevandernaald It's really nice to use in certain situations, e.g proving $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n}$ diverges. Better yet, the proof is a pretty easy consequence of the fact that the function you're evaluating is decreasing monotonically

Comment: I just got done going through some notes on the technique and it's super cool.  And you're right @Stoke the proof is dead simple!

Answer (score 1):

As commented, $\frac{n-1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$. Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n-1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}.$$

If your proposed series were convergent, then the left side would converge, and hence the right side would too, a contradiction.

Comment: Nice, but you still must show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} $converges

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to show the divergence :

For $n > 2$, you have that $n-1\geq \frac{n}{2}$ and that imply that $\frac{n-1}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}$, but $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverge, so $\sum_{n-1}{n^2}$ will diverge too

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ definitely converges, right?

Now if your series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ converges, then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ would converge as well.

But that sum is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$.  Does it converge?